# Is there any way to speed up ddrescue?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, ddrescue

I had a 500GB drive HDD crash about 5 days ago. I used `ddrescue` on the important partition a few days ago, and it's been on "Trimming failed blocks" for almost 2 days now.

Original command:

```
ddrescue -n /dev/rdisk1s2 /Volumes/OSXBackup/rdisk1s2.img /Volumes/OSXBackup/rdisk1s2.log
```

Current output:

```
Initial status (read from logfile)
rescued:   248992 MB,  errsize:   1007 MB,  errors:   15867
Current status
rescued:   249021 MB,  errsize:    978 MB,  current rate:    17408 B/s
   ipos:    44405 MB,   errors:   15866,    average rate:     2784 B/s
   opos:    44405 MB,     time from last successful read:       0 s
Trimming failed blocks...
```

The original command used the `ddrescue -n` parameter, and I have restarted the process a few times as needed (and it seemed to pick up right where it left off each time).

Is there any way to speed up this process?

**Edit:** Six hours later, this is the current status:

```
rescued:   249079 MB,  errsize:    920 MB,  current rate:      409 B/s
   ipos:    39908 MB,   errors:   15851,    average rate:     2698 B/s
   opos:    39908 MB,     time from last successful read:       0 s
Trimming failed blocks...
```

It appears that while "errors" is counting down excruciatingly slowly, ipos/opos is counting down how much data it has to churn through, and it seems to be working at a rate of 750MB/hour. At this rate, it will complete in ~53 hours. Yikes.

**Edit #2:** Two days later, still running. However, there is hope. It has moved passed the "Trimming failed blocks" portion, and on to the next phase "Splitting failed blocks". If anything, what should be taken away from viewing this question is that this definitely takes a long time when a good amount of data/errors are involved. My only hope is that I can successfully recover some important data when all is said and done.

```
rescued:   249311 MB,  errsize:    688 MB,  current rate:        0 B/s
ipos:    26727 MB,   errors:   15905,    average rate:     1331 B/s
opos:    26727 MB,     time from last successful read:      20 s
Splitting failed blocks...
```

Comment: Its by design, most likely. It does multiple passes to extract as much data out as possible

Comment: Crash a smaller hard drive next time ;-)

Comment: My 4TB has taken 3 weeks to get to the Trimming phase... (I'm _pretty sure_ it's all backed up, but doesn't hurt to rescue ;)) ... and thanks to @nza, I'm just hoping I'll get finished by Christmas

Comment: Well... this morning I calculated it had about a week to go based on the speed of the trimming, and voila! It's done! So ~ 3 weeks to get to trimming and ~3 weeks trimming. Scraping was really fast even though it was 1.93% of data - I guess the good and bad data is fast... just the in between horrifically slow? (I'm running again with `-M` just in case this morning's reboots and dist-upgrade made some sort of mess)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I observed that using the `-n` (no-split) option together with `-r 1` (retry once) and setting `-c` (cluster size) to a smaller value can help.

My impression is that the splitting step is very slow as `ddrescue` splits and splits again the damaged areas. This takes a lot of time because `ddrescue` tries to restore very small portions of data. So, I prefer to use `-n` (no-split) together with `-c 64`, `-c 32`, `-c 16`, a.s.o.

Probably the `-n` (no-split) should always be used for one first pass in forward and reverse directions. It seems that the more the data were split, the slower the cloning, although I'm not sure about this. I assume the larger the non-treated areas, the best when running `ddrescue` again, because more contiguous sectors are to clone.

As I'm using a logfile, I don't hesitate to cancel the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when the data read speed becomes two low.

I also use the `-R` (Reverse) mode and after a first pass it often gives me higher speeds reading backwards than forward.

It's not clear to me how already retried sectors (`-r N`) are handled when running the `ddrescue` command again, especially when alternating forward (default) and reverse (`-R`) cloning commands. I'm not sure if the number of times they were tried is stored in the logfile and probably the work is done again useless.

Probably the `-i` (input position) flag can help speed up things too.

Comment: Are you using GNU `ddrescue` or `dd_rescue`?  The `-n` option in GNU ddrescue is `--no-scrape`, not "no-split"

Comment: I had a 3 hour clone that was reduced to 30 minutes by using -c 16. the default was 128. I would have thought that having it be larger would have been faster.

Comment: @endolith no-split is the old name mechanism which was replaced with no-scrape https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddrescue/2015-09/msg00001.html

Answer (score 10):

It can be very hard to see the progress of `ddrescue`, but there is another command included called `ddrescuelog`.

A simple command `ddrescuelog -t YourLog.txt` will output these nice infos:

```
current pos:     2016 GB,  current status: trimming
domain size:     3000 GB,  in    1 area(s)
rescued:     2998 GB,  in 12802 area(s)  ( 99.91%)
non-tried:         0 B,  in    0 area(s)  (  0%)

errsize:     2452 MB,  errors:   12801  (  0.08%)
non-trimmed:   178896 kB,  in 3395 area(s)  (  0.00%)
non-split:     2262 MB,  in 9803 area(s)  (  0.07%)
bad-sector:    10451 kB,  in 19613 area(s)  (  0.00%)
```

You can even use it while `ddrescue` is running...

Comment: 3 weeks to get my 4TB to get to Trimming:
```errsize:   289420 MB,  errors:   34926  (  7.23%)
non-trimmed:   288130 MB,  in 105407 area(s)  (  7.20%)
  non-split:     1243 MB,  in  185 area(s)  (  0.03%)
 bad-sector:    47490 kB,  in 92728 area(s)  (  0.00%)``` ;( ... but thanks heaps for the command!

Answer (score 6):

I have found that playing with the -K parameter you can speed things up. From what I've seen if ddrescue finds an error when running with the -n option tries to jump a fixed amount of sectors. If it still can't read it jumps double the size. If you have large damaged areas you can indicate a big K value (for example 100M) and so the jumping on an error will be larger the first time and it will be easier to avoid problematic areas quickly in the first past.

By the way, there is a wonderful graphical application to analyze the log.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ddrescueview/

Comment: That graphical program is awesome

Answer (score 5):

If your aim is to obtain the bulk of the data intact, then you could speed up its extraction. But if you really want to rescue as much data as possible, then letting ddrecue nibble at each and every is the route to take.

Comment: How exactly to do that?

Answer (score 4):

One more way to monitor ddrescue's progress (on Linux, at least) is through the use of strace.

First, find the PID for the ddrescue process using "ps aux | grep ddrescue"

```
root@mojo:~# ps aux | grep ddrescue
root     12083  0.2  0.0  15764  3248 pts/1    D+   17:15   0:04 ddrescue --direct -d -r0 /dev/sdb1 test.img test.logfile
root     12637  0.0  0.0  13588   940 pts/4    S+   17:46   0:00 grep --color=auto ddrescue
```

Then run "strace" against that process.  You'll see something like:

```
root@mojo:~# strace -p 12083
Process 12083 attached - interrupt to quit
lseek(4, 1702220261888, SEEK_SET)       = 1702220261888
write(4, "\3101\316\335\213\217\323\343o\317\22M\346\325\322\331\3101\316\335\213\217\323\343o\317\22M\346\325\322\331"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1702220261376, SEEK_SET)       = 1702220261376
read(3, "\3101\316\335\213\217\323\343o\317\22M\346\325\322\331\3101\316\335\213\217\323\343o\317\22M\346\325\322\331"..., 512) = 512
lseek(4, 1702220261376, SEEK_SET)       = 1702220261376
write(4, "\3101\316\335\213\217\323\343o\317\22M\346\325\322\331\3101\316\335\213\217\323\343o\317\22M\346\325\322\331"..., 512) = 512
^C
```

...and so on.  The output is fast and ugly, so I then pipe it through "grep" to filter out the stuff I care about:

```
root@mojo:/media/u02/salvage# nice strace -p 12083 2>&1|grep lseek
lseek(4, 1702212679168, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212679168
lseek(3, 1702212678656, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212678656
lseek(4, 1702212678656, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212678656
lseek(3, 1702212678144, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212678144
lseek(4, 1702212678144, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212678144
lseek(3, 1702212677632, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212677632
lseek(4, 1702212677632, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212677632
lseek(3, 1702212677120, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212677120
lseek(4, 1702212677120, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212677120
lseek(3, 1702212676608, SEEK_SET)       = 1702212676608
^C
```

In that example, the "1702212676608" equates to "the amount of data that still needs to be processed on that 2 Tb disk you're trying to salvage."  (Yeah.  Ouch.)  ddrescue is spitting out a similar number -- albeit as "1720 GB" -- in its screen output.

strace gives you a MUCH higher granularity data stream for you to examine; it's one more way to evaluate the speed of ddrescue and estimate a completion date.

Running it constantly is probably a bad plan since it would compete with ddrescue for CPU time.  I've taken to piping it to "head" so I can grab the first 10 values:

```
root@mojo:~# strace -p 4073 2>&1 | grep lseek | head
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: There's `strace -e lseek …` for that – though `pv -d <pid>` might be prettier.

Answer (score 2):

What is the file system of the hard disk where you save the rescue image and the logfile? I just made the experience that rescuing a 500GB internal hard drive (connected via SATA) on a Laptop running Linux Mint from a USB Stick, saving the rescue image and logfile on an `exFat` formatted USB hard drive, was starting rather slowly (1-2MB/sec) but after around 250GB it was only crawling at <100KB/sec. It seemed to become slower the larger the rescue image file was growing.

Then I moved the rescue image and logfile to another temporary place, re-formatted the USB hard drive with the `ext4` file system, moved the files back on it and resumed the ddrescue process - and now it runs with 1-20MB/sec again (fluctuating but around 7MB/sec on average)!

Seems like `exFat` does not play very well with very large files (several hundred gigabytes).

Answer (score 0):

For a faster and quick option to rescue the disc you can use a sh script file and run the file with "sh filename.sh". It contains this line shown, just repeat "sudo ddrescue" and "sleep 3" few more times, the sleep is used to make the drive rest some seconds, it can be good for some reasons:

```
#! /bin/sh -e  
sudo ddrescue -d -r0 -e +0 -T 1s -n /dev/drivepartition file.img log.logfile 
sleep 3
```

The -r0 is with no replies.
The -e +0 is for exit on 1 error. The -T 1s exits  with 1 second fail read. There are options that can be used as -d for direct and -n for no scrape which can speed up.

You can use -R after finish with option -A once, that will reverse and remove all errorsize and start again backwards. Means it will read errors differently.

Answer (score -3):

[dd_rhelp](http://www.kalysto.org/utilities/dd_rhelp/index.en.html) is a shell script that uses dd_rescue "[...] on your entire disc, BUT it will try to gather the maximum valid data before trying for ages on bunches of badsectors"

it's quite old (2012) but still works. haven't tried ddrescue yet.

Comment: The question is about GNU ddrescue (NOT dd_rescue), which precisely is an improved replacement of this script.